# Идентификатор не найден

Tags: c++

Читал в одной книге, что если вам нужно делать одно действие несколько раз, то можно создать "void", в котором прописать это действие и вызывать его по необходимости. Я это и сделал и при попытке скомпилировать мне выдает ошибку C3861: "Crypt: идентификатор не определен". Кода пока в ней нету, это только каркас.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iso646.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
int key, i, n, func = 0;
char original[80];
char code;

cout << "Что вы хотите выполнить: шифрование(1) или дешифрование(2): ";
cin >> func;

if (func == 1) {
    Crypt();
}
else if (func == 2) {

}
else
    cout << "Вы выбрали неверное действие." << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}

void Crypt() {

cout << "privet?";
}

void encrypt() {


}
```

void'ы находятся вне int main если что

Comment: Такая странная штука в книге написана, а то что этот void должен быть объявлен до его первого использования - нет...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно прототипы функций указывать до использования:

```
using namespace std;

void Crypt();
void encrypt();

int main() {
```

Comment: @AnT, гугл говорит так: _"Прототипом функции в языке Си или C++ называется объявление функции, не содержащее тела функции, но указывающее имя функции, арность, типы аргументов и возвращаемый тип данных. В то время как определение функции описывает, что именно делает функция, прототип функции может восприниматься как описание её интерфейса."_ Почему ты говоришь, что это не прототипы? И что это тогда?